# TestCafe How to share runner in the global scope?

Tags: e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe(TC) and writing a test which implements multiple tests in a single TC test. This is for an investment reporting app.

Clients are offered a view of their portfolios, with assets grouped into various categories.

The app offers a "current month" view, with the ability to switch to previous month's data -- called AsOfDates. Within each monthly view, the data is organized into various periods; e.g., CYTD, FYTD, 1Year, 3Years... etc each of which offers a view of the portfolio over the respective time period.

There are numerous graphs throughout the app, with different display specs for the graph type (line, bar, ...): for example how many x-axis points there are for each period and how they are labelled.

I have a working TC regression test that: loops thru multiple clients; loops through the AsOfDates; loops through the available Periods; and examines the various graphs to ensure that the x-axis data is presented according to spec.

In the event of one or more failures I simply collect information documenting the failure and continue to the end of the test.

When the test completes, I create a success or failure report which we can use in our CI/CD pipeline. When done, I want to quietly close the TC task so that it doesn't also generate a test report.

To do that I've been told I need to share the TC runner in the global scope and use the global.runner.stop() stop method.

I'm curently using the TC/CLI approach:
`testcafe chrome ... src/pages/regression/graphDataPoints.js`

How can I grab the runner to do this or do I have to write my own script using `testcafe.createRunner()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Create your own script using `testcafe.createRunner()` and pass options from CLI to `runner`.
2. Fork the reporter that you use, modify it in the way you want, and use it in your tests. In the reporter, you can add a condition when it has to show messages.